# ndk-build error: 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Tags: android, c++, stl

I have a problem with ndk-build (**ndk-r9c**)

**Error:**

```
Common/LCXPlayerSocket.h:206:2: error: 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

**Info:**

My Application.mk

```
APP_MODULES         := MyLib
APP_OPTIM           := $(COMPTYPE)
APP_ABI             := $(TYPE_ARMEABI)
APP_PLATFORM        := $(PLATFORM)
APP_STL             := $(STL_VERSION)
```

My config.bat

```
set TYPE_ARMEABI=armeabi-v7a
set PLATFORM=android-8
set STL_VERSION=stlport_static //does not working on <gnustl_static>
```

**Src file:**

```
include <string.h>

class abc

{

protected:

 std::string m_buffer; //line 206

}
```

**The bug was resold:**

***thx @Violet Giraffe***

> @ndtran: remove set STL_VERSION from your .bat. Add this to
>   Application.mk: APP_STL := gnustl_static –  Violet Giraffe 6 mins ago

Thx for your help.
[D]

Comment: `<string.h>` is an ancient header: `#include <string>`

Comment: missing # in front of include is a typo?

Comment: ---@marcin_j: yep, I do :) Because I do not at ## on post.
---@DieterL: Error: fatal error: string: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `include <string.h>` with `include <string>`

Comment: I have fail too:

jni/../LCXPlayer/include/Common/LCXPlayerSocket.h:9:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
                  ^

Comment: @@Violet Giraffe:
It's show different error (fatal error: string: No such file or directory)

Comment: @ndtran: remove `set STL_VERSION` from your .bat. Add this to Application.mk: `APP_STL := gnustl_static`

Comment: @ndtran: at least, that's how I configure it. Your error obviously points to a problem locating STL.

Comment: -@Violet Giraffe: It working when I change your idea --<remove set STL_VERSION from your .bat. Add this to Application.mk: APP_STL := gnustl_static>--